# Is there a better way to create a custom analytics dashboard tailored for different users?

Tags: reactjs, bigdata, analytics

I am currently developing a dashboard where a user is gonna login to this dashboard and is gonna be displayed with some complex analytics. This analytics is gonna have a lot of charts and KPI metrics which is similar to something like [this](https://dribbble.com/shots/16559247-Sales-Report-Dashboard).

For my current implementation, there is some data stored in firestore firebase which is owned by the user and this data will change everyday, therefore whenever I want to display the analytics, I use where clauses and aggregate functions provided by firebase to query the data and display the analytics on my frontend Reactjs template code. (BTW I am using tremor.so library for the charts UI)

Now I know that when it comes to analytics dashboards, it is a solved problem and there are tons of software like powerBI, Google analytics, Google data studio, Tableau etc. The problem with my use case scenario is that each user has different data and therefore the dashboard needs to be able to display charts with their data only. Therefore, the existing analytics tools are not the solution for me.

Also keep in mind that this software is expected to be used by thousands of users eventually so the solution should be scalable.

I know there must be a better way to do this so I would love someone who is experienced in something similar to this to comment on this.

Thanks